# undefined method `plantposts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first app since finishing the tutorial at railstutorial.org and everything was going well until this. In my app each user can create plants and each plant can have many plantposts. I have put a form to create new plantposts on the plants/id (show) page which I cannot get working. I suspect it may have to do with the routes file.

Here are my controllers:

```
class PlantpostsController < ApplicationController

before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def create
#@plantpost = Plantpost.new(plantpost_params)
#@plant = Plant.find(params[:plant_id])
@plantpost = @plant.plantposts.build(plantpost_params) #this seems to be the main problem line.

if @plantpost.save
  flash[:success] = "Plantpost created!"
  redirect_to    plant_path(@plantpost.plant_id)
else
   flash[:danger] = "No Plantpost created!"
  @plantpost_feed_items = []
  redirect_to plant_path(id: params[:plant_id]  )   
end
end
def destroy
@plantpost.destroy 
flash[:success] = "Plantpost deleted"
redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
```

end

private

```
 def plantpost_params
  params.require(:plantpost).permit(:content, :picture, :user_id, :plant_id)
end

def correct_user
  @plantpost = current_user.plantposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @plantpost.nil?
 end
 end
```

My Plants Controller

```
class PlantsController < ApplicationController

before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :update,
                                     :destroy, :show]
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:destroy, :update ]

def new
@plant = Plant.new
end

def index
 @plant_feed_items = current_user.plants.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
 @plants = current_user.plants.all
 @plant =  Plant.new
end

def show   
 @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
 @plantpost_feed_items  = @plant.plantpost_feed.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
 @plantposts = @plant.plantposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @plantpost = Plantpost.new
end
private
   def plant_params
      params.require(:plant).permit( :notes, :plantname,:source, :planted, :harvested, :yield, :yieldunits)
   end
   def correct_user
      @plant = current_user.plants.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @plant.nil?
   end
       def plantpost_params
      params.require(:plantpost).permit(:content, :picture, :user_id, :plant_id)
    end
```

The relevant parts of the model relationships

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :plants, dependent: :destroy
has_many :plantposts, through: :plants,  dependent: :destroy

class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :plantposts, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

class Plantpost < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :plant
belongs_to :user
```

And the routes file

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'password_resets/new'

 get 'password_resets/edit'

root                'static_pages#home'
get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'

delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'


 resources :users do
  member do
   get :following, :followers
  end
end

resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :plantposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :plants
 #post    'plants'  => 'plantposts#create'
```

end

As you can see from all the hashtags I have been trying a lot of combinations hoping to stumble across the right one.
I have also written an integration test in which this line "     post plant_path(@plant.id), plantpost: { content: "" }" gets this response

> ERROR["test_plantpost_interface", PlantpostInterfaceTest, 1.515159549]
>   test_plantpost_interface#PlantpostInterfaceTest (1.52s)
>   ActionController::RoutingError:         ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] >"/plants/980190962"
>              test/integration/plantposts_interface_test.rb:16:in `block in 
>   <class:PlantpostInterfaceTest>'
>   test/integration/plantposts_interface_test.rb:16:in`block in  '

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is nest the resources.
In your routes file, change

```
resources :plantposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :plants
```

to

```
resources :plants do
  resources :plantposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the routes file and redid some of the named paths and while my tests are getting a little further along I still am getting the "undefined method `plantposts' for nil:NilClass" error in my plantposts controller. Of course when I use the IRB console everything works fine, but when I run the app I get the exception although all the parameters are coming through fine.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a syntax problem. The working create code is:

```
def create
 @plant = Plant.find_by(id: params[:plant_id] )

 @plantpost = @plant.plantposts.build({:plant_id => params[:plant_id], :user_id =>   current_user.id, :content => params[:plantpost][:content], :picture => params[:plantpost][:picture]})
 if @plantpost.save
  flash[:success] = "Plantpost created!"
   redirect_to plant_path :id =>  @plant.id 
 else
  @plantpost_feed_items = []
  render  'plants/show', :id =>  @plant.id 
 end
end
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it but I'm moving on.